# How to remove or hide site actions and ribbon elements?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

A coworker installed a solution package meant to demonstrate a product called "ShowMe For SharePoint" on a few site collections in our SharePoint 2010 farm. It created an item in the Site Actions menu and also a new ribbon tab. The solution has since been removed but the menu items remain!

How do I remove or hide them?

I have checked in the master page and in the XML files that define the usual menu elements but did not find any reference to the ShowMe items. I would prefer to remove the items at their source instead of hiding them using JS or CSS.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

its hard to say how to remove from source without seeing his code. have you checked to see if there are any features still active that relate to "showMe"?

without the code you wouldnt know what he did to make the new custom ribbon tab

hope this helps :)